# Fiction vs Creative-Writing

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have two tags that describe basically the same thing: Fiction and Creative-Writing. Fiction is described as "a form of prose writing that deals with at least partly artificial or imagined events and characters. This tag should be used for any questions relating to fiction, including fiction formatting and technique, fiction critiques, and the publishing of fiction." Creative-Writing is described as "a vague term, but generally means fiction, or writing that's not non-fiction, technical, or business writing." I don't think we need both, especially considering one references the other. Have there been any circumstances where the Creative-Writing tag would work but not the Fiction tag? Should we just use one of these tags? If not, can we further flesh out the differences between the two?

Comment: There is actually a question for this…: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/7093/what-is-the-difference-between-creative-writing-and-fiction-writing, the difference seemed vague to me too, but the OP is saying these are different subjects at his school (and not all creative writing is fiction?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not all creative writing is fiction as generally understood, *but* a tag as broad as "all creative writing, whether narrative, scripts, poetry, essays, humor, etc" seems to me to be too broad to be useful.  I propose getting rid of the creative-writing tag, which would need to start with making sure that every question with that tag has at least one other (more-specific) tag.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around online, **Fiction** seems to refer to *narrative* (novels, short stories), while **Creative Writing** includes poetry, personal essays, persuasive writing (ad-copy, speeches), some types of journalism (travel and food), biographies and histories that are written in a narrative style.

There's a wiki entry for "Creative Nonfiction":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_nonfiction

It seems "Fiction" is the narrower, specific term.